# HTML Adjust table width does not have any effect

Tags: php, html, css

I tried to make a striped with 5 columns.

The column size should be

10% width --- 10% width --- 40% width --- 20% width --- 20% width

Currently this is my code, but the table does not resize to my desired width (the 'description' does not look like the width = 40%)

[image]

Can someone advice whats wrong here?

Here is my code:

```html
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="panel panel2">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                   
                   
                    <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width: auto !important;  >
                   
                   
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th width="10%">ID
                          </th>
                          <th width="10%">File
                          </th>
                          <th width="40%">Description
                          </th>
                          <th width="20%">Date</th>
                          <th width="20%">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <?php  
                        $data = mysqli_query($sql_con,"SELECT * FROM noticeboard");
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
                         ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="width:10%;"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                          <td>
                          <?php 
                          $file = $row['file'];

                          $filetype = strtolower(pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                            if ($filetype =="jpg" || $filetype =="png" || $filetype =="jpeg") {
                                echo "<a href = '$file' target='_blank'><i class='far fa-file-image file-icons' style='font-size:50px; color: #333'></i></a>";
                            }
                            else if($filetype =="docx" || $filetype =="doc"){
                              echo "<a href = '$file' target='_blank'><i class='far fa-file-word file-icons' style='font-size:50px; color: #333'></i></a>";
                            }
                            else{
                              echo "<a href = '$file' target='_blank'><i class='far fa-file-pdf file-icons' style='font-size:50px; color: #333'></i></a>"; 
                            }
                          ?>  
                          </td>
                          <td><span><?php echo $row['notice_desc']; ?></span></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['ndatetime']; ?></td>
                          <td>
                            <a href="update_noticeboard.php?value=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-rounded"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-rounded" data-toggle = "modal" data-target= "#exampleModaldep<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>

                            <!-- MODEL -->
                          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModaldep<?php echo $row['id'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete File</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                Do you really want to delete this file?
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                <a href="delete_noticeboard.php?value=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-rounded">YES</a>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-rounded" data-dismiss="modal">NO</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <!-- content-wrapper ends -->
```

Comment: Seems to work fine here when running the snippet.

Comment: Its not working on the actual code, so strange

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check (sorted from most to less likely in my opinion):

1. The lines within the column do not break causing the column to extend until the end of the line (have you set `white-space: nowrap;` within the cells/paragraphs/rows/columns?)
2. The viewport is extended beyond the screen. That seems unlikely since the other columns "appear" correctly sized (have you set a width property on table or higher levels?)
3. Some css style is preventing the third column from applying the width (have you set any css rules regarding columns width such as `n-th child` of `nth last-of-type`? maybe a `media` rule?)
4. Some javascript rule is applying a style on page load, timeout or other action (e.g., click, change)

I believe that your problem is the first one since the lines do not break in the image you have provided. However, without seeing the entire code, one can only make guesses